# Updating responses while the user sees them

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, responses

When I comment to a post from StackOverflow I like to keep the page opened in a tab and to refresh it to see when someone gives me a reply.

I see the reply and maybe I comment again.

When I go to my profile I see the tab "Responses" with a **big blue number** that represents the number of responses.

What I **don't like** is that also see the responses to my comments what **I've already seen** refreshing the page.

Is possible to detect when the user "sees" the response and update the number of them in the responses tab?

Comment: From what we've been able to tell, there is not a separate "unread" flag per-message. There is simply a *count* of the number of new messages you haven't seen yet, and it highlights that many of them in the list when you open the inbox, then resets the count to 0. (This, of course, still needs dev confirmation, but that's how it appears to act.)

Comment: This is the idea: there are messages that I've seen, already and I would be nice to be implemented.

Comment: I would like that too, but I think it's a "too much work for too little return" matter. I'd be happy to be wrong, though.

Comment: I agree with John, I'm in a post, I send message, refresh, get answer, aswer to comment and when I go to profile I get 1 unseen response, the profile page shoul check if I already comment on that thread and remove the count for that thread. I understand that it would be much complicated to check if I saw the respons without commenting on thread, but if I also commented after the response then clearly there is no reason for me to see the notification